# Global Int variable method for multiple methods

Tags: java, methods, global-variables

I have to set up a math program that supplies random questions to the user based on their year level, and if they're doing well raise the difficulty. I've set up this code here that runs through questions and if they meet the requirements it displays the harder questions, however if "i" that i use to determinate how member questions they've done if separate the program will run the harder questions then go back and finish the easier questions

So basically I've tried to write a method for global "i" which all other methods will use, however when i replace "i" with the method it stops counting and continues to display questions infinitely and i don't know how to fix this.

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Date; 

public class Quiz {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int answer;
        int correct;
        double current_score = 100.00;
        //      int i = 0;

        while (questionsDone() < 10) { // start of question loop

            int random = (int) (Math.random() * 9 + 0);
            int random2 = (int) (Math.random() * 9 + 0);

            System.out.print("What is the sum of" + " ");
            System.out.print(random);
            System.out.print(" + " + random2 + " ");
            System.out.print("=" + " ");

            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            //answer
            answer = scan.nextInt();

            correct = random + random2;

            if (answer == correct) { // start of result display
                System.out.println("You are correct");
            } else if (answer != correct) {
                System.out.println("That wasn't right");
                current_score = (current_score - 10.00);
            }

            System.out.println("Your current percentage is " + current_score); // end of result display

            // i++; // raise number of questions given by 1
            if (questionsDone() == 5 && current_score >= 75) { // code to move up or down year level
                System.out.println("You are doing well! Let's increase the difficulty a little");
                Year1_10Questions();
            }

        }

    }

    public static void Year1_10Questions() {

        int i = 0;
        int answer;
        int correct;
        double current_score = 100.00;
        while (i < 10) { // start of question loop

            int random = (int) (Math.random() * 9 + 0);
            int random2 = (int) (Math.random() * 9 + 0);
            int random3 = (int) (Math.random() * 2 + 1);

            String operator = "";
            switch (random3) {
                case 1:
                    operator = "+";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    operator = "-";
                    break;
            }

            System.out.print("What is the sum of ");
            System.out.print(" " + random + " ");
            System.out.print(operator + " ");
            System.out.print(random2 + " ");

            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            //answer
            answer = scan.nextInt();

            if (random3 == 1) {
                correct = random + random2;

                if (answer == correct) { // start of result display
                    System.out.println("You are correct");
                } else if (answer != correct) {
                    System.out.println("That wasn't right");
                    current_score = (current_score - 10);

                }
            } else if (random3 == 2) {
                correct = random - random2;

                if (answer == correct) { // start of result display
                    System.out.println("You are correct");
                } else if (answer != correct) {
                    System.out.println("That wasn't right");
                    current_score = (current_score - 10);

                }

            }
            System.out.println("Your current percentage is " + current_score); // end of result display

            i++; // raise number of questions given by 1

        }

    } // end of year 1_10 questions

    public static int questionsDone() {
        int i = 0;
        i++;
        return i;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since all the methods are in the same class, you can define `i` on class level:

```
public class Quiz {
    static int i;
    ...
}
```